# Is Using EF Core Value Converter Preventing the Contains() LINQ Method from being Translated to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I have a `Movie` class. It has a `Genres` property of type `List<string>`. I use this exact [EF Core Value Conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#collections-of-primitives) to store it in the database as a comma-separated string.

In my method, I have `movies`, which is of type `IQueryable<Movie>`. The method receives genres as a `List<string>`, and I want to filter the movies according to the genres.

When I apply this filter, this query fails to translate to the database.

```
var genre = "Drama";
movies = movies.Where(m => m.Genres.Contains(genre));
```

The filter works if I apply `.ToListAsync()` to `movies` and pull all the movies to the client-side. But I'm trying to find a way to do this on the database-side.

I've also tried these variations:

```
movies = movies.Where(m => m.Genres.Any(g => g.Contains(genre)));
movies = movies.Where(m => m.Genres.Any(g => g == genre));
```

I'm pasting in the error message below:

> .Where(m => m.Genres
> .Contains(__genre_0))' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

If you want to reproduce it on your computer:

- Clone [this github repository](https://github.com/erhanalankus/FreeFlix/tree/filter-translation-issue) (filter-translation-issue branch)
- Put a breakpoint on `SearchMoviesExtendedQuery.cs`, line 53.
- Run the project(`API` should be the startup project), it will create the `FreeFlixDatabase` SQL Server database and seed ten movies, then it will open Swagger UI.
- In the Swagger UI, run the `/api/catalog/MoviesSearch` POST method with the message body: `{"genres":["string"]}`

Comment: Properties with Value Converter cannot be used in LINQ Query, it is known limitation.

Comment: They can be used if you cast the property you are searching.
queryable.Where(x => ((string)(object)p.ConvertibleProperty) == "sup")

But there has to be a better way..

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1:** As mentioned by John above, you can cast to a string an compare in that way:

`queryable.Where(x => ((string)(object)p.ConvertibleProperty) == "sup")`

**Approach 2:**
I see that this cannot be done directly on the db-side right now. But as you mention, it can be done on the server-side (you called this client side) after a `ToListAsync()`.

```
        var r = _context.TblExample.Where(w => w.Filter == filter);
        if (await r.AnyAsync())
        {
            var rs = await r.ToListAsync();
            var w = rs.Where(w => w.Categories.Contains(category));
            return w.ToList();
        }
```

**Another approach:** Not sure of your exact requirements, but you could also consider a timed job to sync the data from this table into another table specially structured for filtering.