# Fetch Serialised List of String in EF Core Where Clauses

Tags: .net, serialization, entity-framework-core

```
public class Post
{
   public string Id { get; set;}
   public string BodyText { get; set;}
   public List<string> HashTags { get; set;}
}
```

`HashTags` is set to be serialised in SQL Server and then deserialised to `List<string>` in .Net Code.
I want to fetch the list of posts that contains some keywords in `HashTags` List like this

```
var keyword = "ab";
var posts = await _appDbContext.Posts.Where(x => x.HashTags.Contain(keyword));
```

However, it gives me the exception saying that Cannot translate Contains function and tell me

```
 Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()
```

`AsEnumerable()` fetch all records and then apply filter in client side .Net Code but it negatively affects the efficiency in performance. Is there any better solution for this problem?

Comment: How do you store `HashTags` in db?

Comment: Actually ```HashTags``` is string in db because 
```builder.Entity<Posts>().Property(e => e.HashTags).HasConversion(v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v, new JsonSerializerSettings() {NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore}), v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(v, new JsonSerializerSettings() {NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore}));```
this is serialising list of string to string in db and then fetch the string out to .net code by deserialising to list of string.

Comment: Here's similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72054486/is-using-ef-core-value-converter-preventing-the-contains-linq-method-from-bein and there's no answer

Comment: I found a solution in the similar question. Someone says to use property casting for the convertible property to do the filtering in db. ```queryable.Where(x => ((string)(object)x.ConvertibleProperty).Contains(keyword)) ``` However, I dont know how is the searching performance for this type casting solution